# django nginx : How to solve Server Error (500)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx

Python3.7
Django2.1
centOS7
gunicorn
nginx

I am setting up a production environment.

`sudo gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp.wsgi:application`

After executing this, if you access the IP address, error (500) will occur.

`less /var/log/nginx/access.log`

There is no error in checking this.

```
#gunicorn.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IPaddress;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /var/www/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

What should I check?

Comment: The above must be `nginx.conf`, not `gunicorn.conf`. Can you navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: Check the Nginx error log.